# Error when trying to debug. VS2012 gives error

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am trying to debug my application. It was working fine but now I get the below error.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PizzaPosManagement.exe

Additional information: An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Could not load file or assembly 'PIzzaPOS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

If I change it to Release mode and compile it, it works fine and the application will run. It has to be a setting but I don't know what.

Comment: Project > Properties > Build tab, Platform target setting.  Probably.

Comment: HI Hans, Did not work so I am trying a re-installation. Thanks for the suggestion